Using 1.8V digital signals with TPS281C100A and AP22653A
I plan to use the following two devices: AP22653A and TPS281C100A and drive the enable pin from 1.8V logic. They are specified for minimum 3V3 operation, but for both inputs the VIH is 1.5V. Would this work or would that not be reliable enough? Series resistance for the enable pin would be 1k. Thanks!

What's the supply voltage of those ICs? Still 1.8V? If not then a translator built with a transistor and one or two resistors will make the system more reliable.

The supply for those is 3V3 and 60V respectively.

It'll probably work but it's better to go for a 1.8-to-3.3 translator (a simple transistor or even a MOSFET such as 7000 or 7002 and 2 resistors, unless you are very size- or space-limited.

Thanks. That is what I was thinking. I think it would work, but because the minimum VOH specification of my outputting device is VCC - 0.45, so it could be as low as 1.35V (even lower if VCC is lower but still in tolerance). I will try and add a translator.
